# Mysql Calculate percentage with group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a requirement to calculate the percentage of customers within first quarter BY customers within first quarter and status is 'Available'. I am doing something like this which is not giving correct results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, COUNT(1) / (select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1) 
FROM table
WHERE Customer is not null and QUARTER(`Creation_Date`)=1 and `Status` = 'Available' 
GROUP BY Customer
```

I want to add group by 'Customer' in first inner select i.e. something like below but that obviously returns more than one rows.

`select count(1) / select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1 
 and Customer = 'ABC'`

Currently its calculating like e.g. 4/225*100.

Need percentage like this using groupby:

for each customer:

```
X = select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1 and Customer = 'X' and Status = 'Available';
Y = select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1 and Customer = 'X';
Z = X/Y*100
```

Can someone please guide?

Comment: Don't mix `distinct` and `group by`. You will likely confuse yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what the percentage requirement means.  Most likely you need to find the percentage of "available" within the whole set.  To do so, you'll need to count the number of "available" and divide it by the total number.  You need to aggregate across all customers, therefore you should not be selecting the customer.  Instead you should be selecting the quarter.  Overall, you SQL might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) AS "quarter",
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Status`='Available' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1) AS "pct"
WHERE
    Customer is not null and QUARTER(`Creation_Date`)=1
GROUP BY
    Customer
```

(Note that I didn't test it, so some minor modifications may be needed.)

Comment: Need percentage like this:

X = select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1 and Customer = 'X' and Status = 'Available';
Y = select count(1) from table where QUARTER(`Creation_Date`) = 1 and Customer = 'X';
Z = X/Y*100

Comment: That's what the SQL from my answer does - just add `and customer=X` to where clause and multiply the fraction by 100

Comment: This is going to give you a bunch of results though - and you're not going to know which is which

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the sub select. You can just count the customers that are available and divide it by the total number of customers. Multiply by 100 if you want to express it as a percentage:

Note that `COUNT` only counts values that are not null. Alternatively, you could use `SUM`, since `COUNT(1)` is essentially the same as `SUM(1)`.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `Status` = 'Available' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(1) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM table
WHERE Customer is not null and QUARTER(`Creation_Date`)=1
```

Comment: Surely SUM Case

Comment: @Strawberry, both will work, because my `case` returns `NULL` for unavailable, and `count` doesn't count nulls. If you would return 1 or 0 depending on the availability, then you would require `SUM`, because count counts every value, even `0`.

Comment: Well, that's true enough I guess.